# Keeping Parentheses in TraditionalForm

Tags: output-formatting, traditional-form

I have an equation that I want to display, emphasizing one part by putting it in parentheses. However, Mathematica removes the unnecessary parentheses. I'm looking to output something like:

[image: Equation]

Comment: Would something like `TraditionalForm@HoldForm@yourExpression` work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TraditionalForm@
 HoldForm[((a Subscript[x, i] + b) - Subscript[y, i])^2/(a^2 + 1)]
```

[image: formatted output]