# How to keep unnecessary parentheses in TraditionalForm?

Tags: linear-algebra, traditional-form

My goal is to keep the parentheses in the following code sample:

```
TraditionalForm@HoldForm[(CenterDot[a, b])]
```

The problem is that Mathematica still removes the unnecessary parentheses. How could I force Mathematica to keep them?

Comment: Somewhat related is [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/220594).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
TraditionalForm[PrecedenceForm[Dot[a, b], 1] + 1]
```